# Extraction of metadata of a file in binary form

Tags: binary, binaryfiles, apache-tika

I am looking to extract the metadata within a file (not filesystem) in its true binary form.

As the location of the metadata is based on the filetype, I am not sure how to find out at where/which data tag can be used to identify the metadata.

I am currently trying to use Apache Tika as they contain the data tag's name in their code to identify the metadata tags, but Tika already parses the data and remove unwanted data, for example: extra 00h when reading some strings.

For example a MP3 file contains ID3 containers that can have metadata with the tags "TIT2", "TPE1", "TPE2","TALB", etc to indicate the type of metadata. But playing with the data in HxD shows that there is also metadata that is stored near the end of the file while not being in an ID3 container.

In the case of a MP3 file:

1. I understand that the metadata is identified with "ID3" as the start. Is there certain hex value in the metadata container to identify the end of it?
2. ID3 is the signature bits of a MP3 file but also the starting point of the metadata container. Is there a way / library / method in Tika that can identify the offset location of the meta data containers (start and end) for other filetypes based on the signature bits?
   Other filetypes example: PDF, JPG, PNG, MP4

Comment: ID3 tags in an MP3 file are held in the ID3 block that starts with `ID3`, but audio metadata isn't there. There is no end marker, you have to parse the ID3 headers to get the size of the block, see https://mutagen-specs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/id3/id3v2.2.html . Most of the other file formats you mention are even more complex...